# Why does this character screw them over?

Tags: plot-explanation, mindhunter-2017

At the end of episode 9 of *Mindhunter*,

> Greg turns in the uncensored Speck interview to the OPR.

Why does he do this? This doesn't seem to benefit anybody.

> Even if he didn't care about the team or their research, it also involves himself in a lie and his boss in the cover-up. He already lied to them, why renege on the agreement not to tell them and make things worse for everybody involved? I can't see any upside to the course of action he takes.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As he says...

> "I can't be part of a cover-up"

and

> "I don't do deceit very well"

He's obviously uncomfortable with the whole thing.

It is self-destructive, to be sure, but it seems he taking a moral stance...albeit anonymously.